# How can i find if a number that has been entered by a user on the second array that contains a 7 and print it. C++

Tags: c++

So this is my code . What it does is it allows an user to make a smaller array from a larger 100 elemnts array to a smaller custom one. For example the user enter that they want an array of 2 elements . Now those 2 elements can be whatever number they want like 27 or 17. I need to know how to make it so that when the user enters an element that contains a 7 in it and prints it out . I know it needs a string element but i have exhausted every possible thing i can do. Im new to c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int a1, j;
    string numbers[100];
 
    // input from user for the wanted array
    cout << "Enter Wanted Array:" << endl;
 
    for (int a1 = 0; a1 < 100; ++a1) 
    {
        cin >> a1;
        if (a1 > 100) 
        {
            cout << "Array is larger then what is allowed" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (a1 < 0) 
        {
            cout << "Array is smaller then what is allowed" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The Wanted Array is: " << a1 << endl;
        }
 
        cout << "Enter the numbers: " << endl;
 
        //  Input from User for the second Array
        for (int i = 0; i < a1; ++i) 
        {
            cin >> numbers[i];
        }
 
        cout << "The numbers are: ";
        for (int n = 0; n < a1; ++n) 
        {
            cout << numbers[n] << "  ";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should get rid of the excess space between lines of code.

Comment: Did you mean to use the same variable `a1` both as the loop counter and to hold user input? What's the role of the outer loop, `for (int a1 = 0; a1 < 100; ++a1)` ?

Comment: igor-tandetnik a1 is used as the the size of the new array that needs to be made by the user and then when checking for the size of the new array and what numbers the user want to enter . Its also used to check if the array is over 100 or under 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you are trying to filter all the array elements that have the digit `7`.

Firstly, you don't need a string input. As a matter of fact, it is much more simple in integer format.

Here is how you do it. For every number that the user inputs in the array, run a `while` loop that isolates every integer, like this :

```
//  Input from User for the second Array
for (int i = 0; i < a1; ++i) {
    cin >> numbers[i];
    
    int num = numbers[i];
    while(num > 0) {
        int temp = num % 10;
        
        if (temp == 7) {
            cout << numbers[i] << " ";
            break; //to get out of the while loop
        }
        
        temp /= 10;
    }
}
```

This will print all the numbers that contain the digit `7`.

Although this will give you the desired result, I must say that your code is very inefficient. Read more on how to write efficient code, it will help you in the long run. Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but i still need to have every number that the user has entered and then after that i need it to print out a secondary array with all the numbers that have a 7 in them . This is a work that my school has given me so idk really what to do due to me not being so familiar with c++

Comment: and the code you sent me will do what i want but it wont allow me to fill up more then 1 element in the new array

Comment: So, instead of printing it out, just store all the elemets with `7` in a new array and print it later. My point was to give you the logic to isolate each digit, how to implement that in your program is completely up to you.